# Adding field by proximity using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, spatial-join, proximity

I'm using ArcMap with the Basic license.

I have turnout gates (points) on or very close to irrigation facilities (lines). The irrigation facilities have a field for type (canal, pipeline, culvert, etc.).

What join tool would I use to only add the facility type attribute to my turnout gates feature class attribute table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [spatial join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) tool and specify an appropriate distance.
That will add the attributes to the feature.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The spatial join added the facility type (and all other facility attributes) to my turnout gates.